# Identificar if e endif com regex?

Tags: php, regex, template

Em um exemplo do SO encontrei:

```
<?php

$a = 22;
$b = 33;

$template = '
[if $b>0 ]
    B > 0
[/if]';

// IF - ENDIF
preg_match_all('/\[if(.*?)\][\s]*?(.*)[\s]*?\[\/if\]/i', $template, $regs, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($regs[0]); $i++) {
    $condition = $regs[1][$i];
    $trueval   = $regs[2][$i];
    $res = eval('return ('.$condition.');');
    if ($res===true) {
        $template = str_replace($regs[0][$i],$trueval,$template);
    } else {
        $template = str_replace($regs[0][$i],'',$template);
    }
}

echo '<h3>Template</h3><pre>'.htmlentities($template).'</pre>';
```

A saída foi:
    B > 0

Logo funcionou perfeitamente, mas não sei onde estou errando para essa outra sintaxe:

```
[if var == true]
    [- success -]
[/if]
```

P.S: O `[- success -]` seria um `echo`, mas não vem ao caso, estou tentando com o seguinte código:

```
private function _if()
{
    // IF - ENDIF
    preg_match_all('/\[if(.*?)\]*?(.*)*?\[\/if\]/', $template, $regs, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($regs[0]); $i++) {
        $condition = $regs[1][$i];
        $trueval   = $regs[2][$i];
        echo "Condition: {$condition}<br>";
        echo "TrueVal: {$trueval}<br>";
        /*
        $res = eval('return ('.$condition.');');
        if ($res===true) {
            $template = str_replace($regs[0][$i],$trueval,$template);
        } else {
            $template = str_replace($regs[0][$i],'',$template);
        }*/
    }
}
```

Creio que o erro esteja na expressão regular, pois nem entra no `for`, pois nem exibe nada nos echos dentro do mesmo. Como faria para pelo menos achar a condição dentro do `[if ]` e funcionar para mais de uma linha? Por exemplo:

```
[if var == true]
    [- success -]
    <p>Oi, tudo bem?</p>
[/if]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No [teste que realizei](https://regex101.com/r/zX3nT7/1) a REGEX funcionou perfeitamente

Contudo creio que seria melhor substituir ela por `~\[if([^\]]*)\]\s*?(.*?)\[\/if\]~s`

Veja funcionando em [REGEX 101](https://regex101.com/r/fY4dU4/1).

A grande jogada esta no modificados `s` que faz com que o `.`(Dot) aceite quebras de linha `\n`.

Então você vai encontrar a condição no grupo 1 e "trueval"(conteúdo) no grupo 2.

#### Nota

- talvez seja interesante trocar `([^\]]*)` por `( [^\]]+)` para garantir que tenha ao menos um condição no `if`.
- `(.*?)` garante que vai pegar o menos conteúdo possível.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, agora estou conseguindo entender!